# Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices

Tags: java, android, gradle

Android Studio 3.6.1 Gradle Version 5.6.4

Gradle Buid Error

Cannot create service of type `TaskExecuter` using `ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter()` as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type `ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry`.

```
Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.
```

Comment: Could you please specify when this error is occurring and if any solutions you have tried to apply also so we can understand and help you.

Comment: when i try to buid a project this error will come

Comment: after updating android studio and gradle this problem occur

Comment: Experienced the same issue when building a Flutter project on Android Studio 3.6.2.  Interestingly, the project builds from Android Studio to Xcode iOS Simulator and runs like a champ.

Answer (score 51):

had same issue, stopping Gradle using the command below fixed it for me:

```
gradle --stop
```

or if you are using wrapper, use:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Comment: works on mac. <3

Comment: works on ubuntu 22.04, too

Answer (score 18):

I simply had to restart my PC for this to get fixed.  Unfortunately I didn't try this until after I tried most of the other solutions.

Comment: Yes works in windows 10 too

Comment: This also works in windows 11

Answer (score 9):

I also had this when I tried building on my ExFAT formatted ssd on macos. Reformatting it using APFS solved it.

Comment: Thanks a Loooooot!!!
Unbelievable this was the problem, I use a partition of ExFAT so I can use it to have mutual shared memory between my Widows partition(NTFS) and my Mac partition(APFS), but from now on Flutter projects only on APFS!

Comment: Flutter Hello World (MyApp)
Host: MacOS
External Disk: ExFAT
Internal Disk: APFS
Target: Android

I can confirm that the Flutter Hello World shows this error when running from the external ExFAT disk.
The same copy of the project runs without errors from the internal disk.

Thank you @TnsKtel.

Answer (score 6):

in flutter or react-native go to android folder and run this in cmd

> gradlew --stop

next

> gradlew clean

to rebuild android or simple so you can restart your computer and run your flutter or react-native project again

Answer (score 4):

did u face this issue in react native,

1. go to android folder
2. open the terminal
3. if u using vscode terminal(powershell) use -> ./gradlew --stop
4. otherwise -> gradle --stop

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who has their project on their **external drive**

- Try moving it to your local drive

This worked for me

(MacOS Monterey)

Answer (score 2):

For me the source of this error was wrong permissions within the project. A `sudo chown -R <username> .` within the project's root fixed those issues.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue in a **react native project** like below in the screenshot when I try to run the app in android **simulator** using `yarn android` then I followed the below steps to resolve the issue which I got from the above

[image]

**Step - 1:** Go to android folder and delete **build** folder.

[image]

**Step - 2:** Run the below command like

`cd android and ./gradlew --stop`

and then you will see a response like `Stopping Daemon(s)`

[image]

**Step - 3:** Now running `cd .. && yarn android` successfully launch the app without the above error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying to deploy another project on the same virtual device. For me it was solved by selecting "Wipe Data" for that Virtual Device in Android Virtual Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up the answer from Alex. I got this issue when my project is in my external drive. I played around with device permission, file permission and even updated my android studio since I use VS Code for my flutter projects.

Finally made a sample project on android studio and thankfully got the same error message from Gradle. In this way, I knew the issue is not related to the VS code. As Alex said, I wiped the data from android device manager. But I got into some other issue. I let the virtual device to start completely and ran the project again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I disabled the "Use detected ADB location" under Emulator Extended Controls > Settings. Restarted the emulator and was able to "Run" without any errors occurring anymore. [Preview of "Use detected ADB location" setting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tnXw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project or performing a clean on any other project except the current one where the error exist solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the caches directory under c:\Users<Your user name directory>.gradle directory  and do the build again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faceed same issues in my flutter project for multiple build process and out of memory then I copy project from one folder to another folder and open project from android studio. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation this worked, I'm using Android Studio on Windows 10

1. I installed JDK and added its installed path into my environment variable under name JAVA_HOME ([follow solution 2][1])
2. just added --stop run configuration on android/gradlew

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
4. ran android/grandlew

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

5. remove --stop that you did step 3 and click on okay
   6.If not work just restart android studio and follow step 4 again
   [1]: https://fluttercorner.com/solved-error-java_home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter-path-in-flutter/
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W77DF.png
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9LWg.png

Answer (score 0):

run this command on
**sudo ./gradlew clean**

Answer (score 0):

**For Flutter**
I have solved it by running

```
cd android
```

then

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Flutter Developer** I have got the same problem.

```
cd android
```

and then run

```
./gradlew --stop
```