# Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: error]

while running the code got this error. I tried to reinstall the flutter ,but did not work

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like a Java error,

Just to have a clear conscience, i would suggest you to run the very classic

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter pub get
```

if you're using build_runner in your project, run:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Restart your computer, it worked for some people with the same problem (Linked at the end).

If nothing of this works, reinstall your Java.

Check this for more info:

[Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557935/cannot-create-service-of-type-taskexecuter-using-projectexecutionservices)

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12436#issuecomment-678389275