# Problem in starting my flutter app (i think it is a build problem)

Tags: flutter, dart, build

I'm sorry if the problem is not explained well enough, I hope if there is something that needs to be displayed as problem information, to be further added.

Basically, I'm pretty new to flutter. I have created myApp and did some work on it. As everything was working fine, suddenly something with the build failed and now everything shows as undefined (i did not add a new dependency or something, just did a rebuild after checking the new introduced functionality is working).[image]

I tried flutter:

1. flutter clean
2. flutter packages get
3. flutter packages update
4. flutter pub get
5. deleting the pubspeck.lock

But i cannot seem to run it. Please help the new guy :).

Basically in the yaml file i haven't done much changes, just added couple dependencies and enabled assets. Here is the pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: app_name
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.4 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  agora_uikit: ^1.3.7
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.2.6
  agora_rtm: ^1.5.9
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.9
  app_popup_menu: ^1.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2
  circular_menu: ^2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/Logo.png
  

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Here is the code of main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:myApp/pages/splash_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After running "flutter pub get" again, the dependencies were resolved, but when tried to start the app again I got the following exception in the terminal.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using method ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #14 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.
   > Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using method ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.
      > Could not create service of type ExecutionHistoryStore using ExecutionGradleServices.createExecutionHistoryStore().
         > Cannot lock execution history cache (/Users/user/Desktop/myApp/my_app/android/.gradle/7.5/executionHistory) as it has already been locked by this process.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question, adding the code from `main.dart`?

Comment: You missed importing the flutter widgets. Add this: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

Comment: @AppSolves oh, my bad, it is there, something went wrong when copying into stackoverflow. This is not the problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: i dont know if this is a procedure here, but I will be happy to share a screen or something?

Comment: And running `flutter pub get` really didn't work? I often have this "issue" too, vscode highlights everything until you run this command (in my case). You could also try to restart your IDE, reloading the plugins may resolve linting problems

Comment: @AppSolves just ran it again and another exception popped up. I will add it to the question

Comment: @AppSolves linting problems are gone, but I still cannot run the app.. :c

Comment: Try the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64017953/19960585). Restarting your PC might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AppSolves for providing guidance, for fixing this issue. The problem was fixed for me after stopping, cleaning gradle build and restarting my PC. Followed the steps here [Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557935/cannot-create-service-of-type-taskexecuter-using-projectexecutionservices/64017953#64017953)